# Can any infinite sum be calculated using the residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

Towards the end of my Intro to Complex Analysis textbook, there were exercises that led the reader through calculating certain infinite sums such as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}$, etc. using the residue theorem.

For most of these sums, the book gave a function that could be used in conjunction with the residue theorem to calculate the values of the infinite sums.

My question is: given some convergent infinite sum, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$, can we find a function $g(z)$ depending on $f(n)$ that can be easily used with the residue theorem to find the value of the sum?

Comment: The question is too general. There is no such general method.

Comment: Already $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}$ can't be expressed in terms of other familiar constants (as far as anyone knows) so can't be calculated this way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant