# General formula for calculating infinite sums

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, residue-calculus

A while age, I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966556/can-any-infinite-sum-be-calculated-using-the-residue-theorem) about general ways to calculate infinite sums using the residue theorem.  Some people in the comments said that there wasn't any general way of using this method.

I was reading [this article](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf), which gave the formula:
$$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty{f(n)} = -\sum\{\text{residues of }π cot(πz)f(z)\text{ at }f\text{’s poles}\}$$

This seems like an *almost* general formula.  The main restriction I see is that the sum goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, instead of $0$ to $\infty$, which we might want.

My questions are:

1. Are there other restrictions that this formula puts on $f$ that doesn't allow us to find *any* infinite sum that sums from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?  I assume $f$ has to be holomorphic, but I don't know if there are any other restrictions.
2. Is there some similar formula that can be used to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{f(n)}$?

Comment: Well $f$, as a function of complex numbers, has to be analytic except at finitely many singularities, $|f(z)|<\frac{M}{z^k}$ along the quadratic path is required.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments to your other question, already there is no way to evaluate $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^3}$ in closed form (that anyone knows), and as you can see this formula does not apply to it (in any obvious way) because taking $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^3}$ causes the positive and negative terms to cancel.